# how can I grep a directory and write the full line found to a file

Tags: linux, grep

I have a string that I'm grepping for in my directory that looks like this:

```
Found an error with id: XXXX
```

I want to be able to take all those lines and write them to a new separate file. Currently I have this:

```
grep -rl "Found an error with id:" . >> errorOutput.txt
```

but that only prints which file contains that string. Any way I could get the full line with the id?

Comment: Remove the `l` flag maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-l` flag is the culprit here. It suppresses the contents in the matched lines and just prints out the files containing the match because of the `-r` recursive search. Even without the `-l` flag you get a `filename:pattern` result.

So to just store the patterns in the file, use an extra `awk` to the pipeline as below.

```
grep -r "Found an error with id:" . | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' > results.log
```

Or with just `grep` just skip printing the filenames with the `-h` flag ( both FreeBSD and GNU variants support this )

```
grep -rh "Found an error with id:" . > results.log
```

and BTW `awk` is powerful in itself, it can do pattern search by itself on the file system. So you could do

```
awk '/Found an error with id:/' * > results.log 2>/dev/null
```